# Avoiding automatic creation of civi contact upon drupal account creation

Tags: drupal

How can I avoid contact creation when a drupal account is created?

My problem is:

Sometimes the contact already exists as an organization. If I add a drupal account, that contact gets duplicated as an individual.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way via the standard config to do this afaik. In theory, if the drupal contact that is created matches a unique email for a civi Individual (that has no drupal user yet) then the match should be made.
Otherwise you have to drive that type of clean up via your dedupe workflow.
Also just spotted you said Organisation. So in theory, again, Drupal users can only be Individuals - since organisations find it hard to use the keyboard. Perhaps that is part of the issue you are needing to resolve?

Comment: Right. This issue is just when the contact is not individual.

So, lets say that my workaround would be to automatically remove the extra contact (the individual one, because I need only the organizational contact type besides the fact that organizations are bad with typing...), is there a way to locate it via its drupal user id?

Comment: i don't quite follow your question so me be giving wrong answers
1/ on a civi contact page there is the ID link back to the connected Drupal User

2/ in the db all the info is in the uf_match table and I think that might be how you can 'override' civi and connect a Drupal User to an Org but comes with usual warnings (backup, pray, drink) ;-)